# При изменении ориентации экрана каждый раз обращаться за данными на Firebase Database Server

Tags: android, firebase

Всем привет! 
Есть Firebase Database с определенным списком данных, который необходимо выводить в RecyclerView. Я это реализовал через интерфейс, чей метод (обратного вызова) благополучно передает данные из onDataChange в мой recyclerViewAdapter и далее в список на экран. Решение подсмотрел  [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)

Принимая во внимание то, что onDataChange метод работает в своей асинхронной манере и сохранять данные (только что вытянутые из Firebase Database) в какой-либо переменной не так просто (или не представляется возможным),

как правильно организовать поведение/отображение данных (вытянутых из БД Firebase и помещенных в RecyclerView) при повороте экрана?
Должен ли я каждый раз при повороте экрана в onSaveInstanceState обращаться к Firebase (вызывая метод onDataChange со всеми остальными приблудами) или существует какой-то элегантный способ с первого раза сохранять данные в какую-то переменную?

Не знаю нужно ли прилагать код к данному вопросу, т.к. никаких ошибок здесь я не обсуждаю, тем не менее, этот вопрос также есть на англоязычной версии с примером моего кода и схемой взаимодействия RecyclerView и БД Firebase [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50256338/should-ondatachange-method-be-called-everytime-when-screen-orientation-has-been)
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь действительно больше архитектурный вопрос в построении приложения, так что особого смысла в обсуждении кода в общем то и нет. 
Каждый раз, при повороте экрана обращаться к БД действительно не очень хорошая идея. Для того, чтобы исключить такие ситуации были разработаны [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/)

Тема достаточно большая для освещения в ответе на вопрос. Но вашу проблему она как раз таки и решает "элегантно".

Comment: Да, спасибо! Уже начал изучать эту библиотеку